# Multiple one-to-many relations in Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring JDBC and I am a bit unsure on how to work with multiple one-to-many relations (or many-to-many). In this case I am injecting a repository into one of my resultsetextractors so that I can retrieve its associations. Is this the way to do it? Is it bad? Are there other better ways?

*Note: I have left out the injection of repository*

```
public class SomeResultSetExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor {

  public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
    List result = new LinkedList();

    while (rs.next()) {
        SomeObject object = new SomeObject(rs.getString(1), rs.getLong(2));
        result.add(object);

        List<AnotherObject> otherObjects = anotherRepository.findAllById(object.getId);
        object.setOtherObjects(otherObjects);
        // and so on
    }

    return result;

  }
}
```

Okey so after reading Dmytro Polivenok answer I have changed to RowMapper interface instead and I am currently using the other repositories to populate all associations  like I show in my example. Is this a good way of doing it?

Comment: Does the repository start a new SQL query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a good practice for Spring JDBC and SQL queries in general is to use one query for each entity.

E.g. assume this model:

- Customer (customerId, name, age, ...)
- Address (customerId, type, street, city, ...)
- PaymentOption (customerId, cardnumber, cardtype, ...)
- Customer 1---* Address
- Customer 1---* PaymentOption

I would build 3 queries, 3 Daos, 3 ResultSetExtractors/RowcallbackHandlers:

- CustomerDao with readCustomerData(Customer or List)
- AddressDao with readAddressForCustomer(Customer or List)
- PaymentOptionDao with readPaymentOptionsForCustomer(Customer or List)

If you would bake this in 1 query, you would have to build some logic to revert the cartasian product.

- I.e. if the customer has 3 addresses and 2 payment options the query would return 6 rows.
- This gets quite hard, if Address or PaymentOption does not have an own primary key.

For many to many:

- Customer * --recommends-- * Product

I would probably build:

- CustomerDao.readRecommendationsAndProductKeys
- getDistinctListOfProductKeysFromRecommendations
- ProductDao.readProducts
- replaceProductKeysByProductsOnRecommendations

Like this you could reuse ProductDao.readProducts for

- Customer * --buys-- * Product or
- ProductGroup 1---* Product

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much the same as I ended up doing.

Comment: Isn't this inefficient as you are making several round trips to the database? Say you have an object that has 3 Collections (One to Many relationships) If you need all the data, your query returns 100 objects, you will in turn issue 300 more queries to get the complete data, for a total for 301 queries

Comment: The idea is to batch each query. You can call readCustomerData with 100 Customer Ids and split the result based on the Customer Id. So for the 100 customers you would still only need 3 queries.

Answer (score 4):

I think that your code will work, but the concern here is about usage of ResultSetExtractor which is mainly for JDBC framework itself, and for most cases [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html) recommends to use RowMapper.

So alternative approach would be to have method in your DAO that selects and maps parent object. Then for each object to invoke other Repository or private method that selects and maps child objects, and then to link child objects with parents based on your relationship type (one-directional or bidirectional). This approach may also allow you to control whether you want to load child objects or not.

For example, you may check Spring PetClinic application which has [SimpleJdbcClinic class](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petclinic/trunk/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/jdbc/SimpleJdbcClinic.java)

If you can use other frameworks, you may consider [mybatis](http://mybatis.github.com/mybatis-3/), it is more about mapping and allows you to control your SQL code.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if I understand your answer properly. Let say you have the classes: Movie, Actor, Genre and Comment. You want to return a movie object with all its associations: One movie have many actors, many comments and one genre. How would you do that?

Comment: You can have getMovies method, which will perform select for movies and genre, and map them to objects. Then for each movie invoke Repository for actors with select/map and Repository for comments with select/map (or if  actors and comments exists in your context only in terms of movies then you can do this in private methods). After this set comments and authors to movie object

Comment: Okey, so if I change to rowmapper interface it is better. However, what do you do with many-to-many cases? What is the best way to map them? Let say each movie has many actors and each actor belongs to many movies. Then you have a join table? Do you create a method in for instance the actor repository which is named findAllActorsForMovie which use the join table and the actor table to create a result? Just as you would in a one-to-many?

Comment: I think there is no standard way of doing this in Spring JDBC as in terms of selects it provides interface for doing SQL and mappings. In case of many to many, you will need to do selects of all associations, map the results and set objects. Decision to have separate repositories for each relationship should be based on type of relationship aggregation vs composition - can actor exist without movie in your context. So if our task is just to load movies with actors I would do this in loadMovies method - perform all selects, mapping and set movies to each actor and actors to each movie